# R cannot be resolved/ No resouce found that matches given name

Tags: android, r.java-file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/BtnRecipe"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="net.androidbootcamp.healthyrecipes.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="Guacamole Recipe"
    android:textSize="34sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:text="View Recipe"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/Guacamole" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/guacamole" />
```

This is my main activity. I am running Juno on windows 8.1.

I know "R cannot be resolved" has been asked so many times i just cannot find an answer that helps me. i have "R" errors on lines 14,21, and 31.

I also have the Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/Guacamole').   activity_main.xml   line 32

I have a project due tomorrow and any help is greatly appreciated, if any has any tips on running Eclispe in 8.1 that would also be appreciated.

Comment: I have already tried cleaning my project and these errors are not resolved.

Comment: This shouldn't have been tagged with Windows 8.1.

Comment: My professor has said to expect complications with windows 8.1, i did not know if this error involved 8.1 or not. sorry.

Comment: No worries. To clarify, the windows-8.1 tag is in fact for "the new features and APIs [Windows 8.1 introduces] for developers of Windows Store apps". In short, please don't use it unless you're developing a Windows Store app, which you aren't.

Comment: `a-z and number,not start with number, no A-Z`

Answer (score 0):

See you at your code again

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
android:src="@drawable/Guacamole" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:src="@drawable/guacamole" />
```

in the second image view the `@drawale/guacamole`is in small and in first one is big `@drawable/Guacamole` thats it.

Comment: Thanks for that, and what line should i add the Import R code?

Comment: well i think the above code should solve your problem but if  it doesn't then write the import code at the top below your package name

Answer (score 0):

error become because you use incorrect name for your drawable.
drawable just can use lowwer case leeter (a-z and number,not start with number)

Answer (score 0):

**While naming images in `res/drawable` folder never use capital letters.** You can use numbers but don't start the name with a number. In your case you have given `Guacamole` which has a capital 'G'.Change it so something else and use the same name in your layout as `android:src="@drawable/somegoodname"`

Also be sure that in your activity, you have not imported `R.android.`, instead of `import R.YOUR PACKAGE NAME.`.

If this doesn't solve your problem please refer [r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error) to find out various reasons of generating this error.